# How to make fill parent for element in left side

Tags: android, android-layout

How to make spinner to fill empty place in left side?
 
`android:layout_width="fill_parent"` does not help.

XML layout:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spn1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Text1" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Text2" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: post full code and what you want exactly. do you want your textViews to be aligned right to the spinner?

Comment: textViews have to be aligned right and Spinner has to fill all empty place

Comment: someone has given the answer and it seems its just like what you want

Comment: Hi @Gosha please use android:layout_weight to solve your problms

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would make use of a Relative Layout and Linear Layout combination to achieve this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/lin_layout" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lin_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="asd" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="fgdas" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The Output,

[image]

Comment: @Andro Selva Thank a lot! It is what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Andro solution's above is perfect as per your need .....

but if data in text view is dynamic and may be too long then can try android:weightSum="1" here

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:weightSum="1" 
       >

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".8" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lin_layout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" 
           android:layout_weight=".2" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="text1" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="text2" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```